# commit or reference 'master' not found - что это значит

Tags: git, phpstorm, commit

PHPStorm показывает такое предупреждение. В инете ничего не могу найти по этому поводу. Что это значит и как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ровно то что написано. У вас нет ветки мастер. Скорее всего вместо неё есть новомодная ветка main.

Comment: ветка master имеется...

Comment: без проблем создаю из неё копию, делаю коммиты, переключаюсь и т.д.

Comment: Очистите кэш, спультесь с репозитория ...

Comment: php artisan config: cache + git pull origin master  - всё тоже самое...

Comment: @ДмитрийТюльпа, кэш PhpStorm'а: `File | Invalidate Cashes...`